# How to build a world with real image as ground plane

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I want to simulate a world where its ground has special pattern.
I decided to make a image file use Photoshop, and put this image into gazebo world as ground plane.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4761/how-to-build-a-world-with-real-image-as-ground-plane/) by [Paul](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/532/paul/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-10-17

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Update: Also check out [this tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=static_map_plugin&cat=build_world).

You can create a material script, and then use that material script on a ground plane.

1. Create a new model directory:

   mkdir ~/.gazebo/models/my_ground_plane
2. Create the materials directories:

   mdkir -p ~/.gazebo/models/my_ground_plane/materials/textures
   mdkir -p ~/.gazebo/models/my_ground_plane/materials/scripts
3. Create your material script file `~/.gazebo/models/my_ground_plane/materials/scripts/my_ground_plane.material` with the following contents:

```
    material MyGroundPlane/Image
    {
      technique
      {
        pass
        {
          ambient 0.5 0.5 0.5 1.0
          diffuse 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
          specular 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.5
    
          texture_unit
          {
            texture MyImage.png
            filtering trilinear
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

5. Copy your image to `~/.gazebo/models/my_ground_plane/materials/textures/MyImage.png`
6. Create a `~/.gazebo/models/my_ground_plane/model.sdf` file with the following contents

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <sdf version="1.4">
    <model name="my_ground_plane">
      <static>true</static>
        <link name="link">
          <collision name="collision">
            <geometry>
              <plane>
                <normal>0 0 1</normal>
                <size>100 100</size>
              </plane>
            </geometry>
            <surface>
              <friction>
                <ode>
                  <mu>100</mu>
                  <mu2>50</mu2>
                </ode>
              </friction>
            </surface>
          </collision>
          <visual name="visual">
            <cast_shadows>false</cast_shadows>
            <geometry>
              <plane>
                <normal>0 0 1</normal>
                <size>100 100</size>
              </plane>
            </geometry>
            <material>
              <script>
                <uri>model://my_ground_plane/materials/scripts/my_ground_plane.material</uri>
                <name>MyGroundPlane/Image</name>
              </script>
            </material>
          </visual>
        </link>
      </model>
    </sdf>
   ```
7. Create a `~/.gazebo/models/my_ground_plane/model.config` file with the following contents

   My Ground Plane
        1.0
        model.sdf

   ```
    <description>
      My textured ground plane.
    </description>
   ```
8. In your world SDF file, use your ground plane like so:

   ```
    <include>
      <uri>model://my_ground_plane</uri>
    </include>
   ```

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Paul](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/532/paul/) on 2013-10-17**:
Thank you so much for this detailed and concise reply!

**Comment by [Paul](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/532/paul/) on 2013-10-18**:
Hi nkoenig, can you tell me how to find the documentation of material. I don't know the meaning of ambient, diffuse and specular

**Comment by [Paul](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/532/paul/) on 2013-10-18**:
I found a bug in your post

**Comment by [Paul](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/532/paul/) on 2013-10-18**:
I found a bug in your post

**Comment by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) on 2021-09-17**:
Does this apply to Ign Citadel as well too? I'm having no luck on that one and I'm hoping it's not a bug